# F# Core library source code has a flag for compiling tuples as structs but I can't make it work

Tags: f#

This is  follow-up question to [this proposal](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6148669-short-tuples-compiled-as-structs-up-to-25x-per).

Apparently, the F# Core library source has a flag that allows 2-tuples to be compiled as structs. See [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L520). I did the following:

- Added a define `TUPLE_STRUXT` flag to `FSharp.Core.fsproj` and `FSharp.Compiler.fsproj`.
- Built with `build.bat`.
- Replaced contents of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.1.0` with appropriate built files.

My project compiles and references the right (newly-built) `FSharp.Core.dll`. However, 2-tuples are still compiled as classes.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this code branch in fact irrelevant? The fact that tuples are compiled to System.Tuple and not the type declared in this code (whether the `TUPLE_STRUXT` flag is set or not) would indicate the latter. Is there a way to make it work?

EDIT: After also setting the flag `FX_NO_TUPLE` the source does not compile. The error I can't get around is `prim-types.fs <527,7>: error FS0039: The type 'Struct' is not defined`. That is, the offending line is the first one of the struct tuple definition:

```
[<Struct>]
type Tuple<'T1,'T2> = 
    new (v1,v2) = { Item1 = v1; Item2 = v2 }
    val Item1 : 'T1 
    val Item2 : 'T2
```

Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: If you look [up a few lines in the source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L503) you'll see it depends on another flag `FX_NO_TUPLE`. You probably need to set that one too.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks! I blame no indents on nested #ifs for not spotting this! However, now the source does not compile. See the edit.

Comment: @Daniel Could you please write your tip as an answer? I'd like to accept it and reopen with the new issue as mydogisbox suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TUPLE_STRUXT` depends on another flag, [`FX_NO_TUPLE`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L503), which should also be set.