# F# Core library fails to compile with flags for struct tuples: "error FS0039: The type 'Struct' is not defined"

Tags: f#

This is a further development of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993904/f-core-library-source-code-has-a-flag-for-compiling-tuples-as-structs-but-i-can) and on advice of esteemed community member mydogisbox posted anew.

I'm trying to compile the F# Core library with flags that will make 2-tuples structs. The flags are `FX_NO_TUPLE` and `TUPLE_STRUXT`. The relevant code begins [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L503).

The `TUPLE_STRUXT` appears in prim-types.fs and tastops.fs so I added the flag to `FSharp.Core.fsproj` and `FSharp.Compiler.fsproj`. `FX_NO_TUPLE` appears in prim-types.fs only so I added it to `FSharp.Core.fsproj`.

After running `build.bat` it fails when it comes to building the core library. There are two main errors:

`prim-types.fsi(1251,10): error FS1175: All record, union and struct types in FSharp.Core.dll must be explicitly labelled with 'StructuralComparison' or 'NoComparison'`

This error can be dealt with by flagging the struct tuple with `StructuralComparison` and `StructuralEquality` in prim-types.fsi

`prim-types.fs <527,7>: error FS0039: The type 'Struct' is not defined`

This one I can't get around. This concerns the very struct tuple definition:

```
[<Struct>]
type Tuple<'T1,'T2> = 
    new (v1,v2) = { Item1 = v1; Item2 = v2 }
    val Item1 : 'T1 
    val Item2 : 'T2
```

`Struct` attribute is successfully used in e.g `seq.fs` in the same Core library. The library has probably not been compiled with struct tuple flags for some development time and something has changed since. Does anyone with a better understanding of this code know how to fix this?